# How to convert NSUserDefaults to CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, nsuserdefaults, database-migration

I have an app that I developed 3+ years ago using Obj C and NSUserDefaults (NSCoding / NSKeyed​Archiver) as my way to saving the data. A few months ago I redesigned the app and thought it would be a great time to redevelop the app but this time using Swift 3 and Core Data. The App is complete but the last part of this puzzle is how to convert my old saved data (NSUserDefaults) into new CoreData entities.

All the examples of migration seem to be coming from an old version of the database (CoreData) and adding some new stuff into it. I'm having a difficult time finding a tutorial or starting point for what I am trying to do. I'm sure it's been done before and probably thousands of times, but I can't seem to find any examples or documentation on it.

I was hoping someone where would be able to point me in the right direction with a tutorial or similar project.

Comment: Why would someone down vote this? Would you like me to list out the books I've read on the topic as well as the online courses I have checked out from Lynda and Udemy. I've done my share of research on this topic and I'm just not finding what I need. I'm sorry if that upsets you.

Comment: A starting point is the code provided in the Xcode Core Data template. The structure of the object model depends strongly on the user defaults structure.

Comment: Why would there be a migration guide from NSUserDefaults to core data? NSUserDefault is for small, simple, independant bits of data of ir not independent then homogenous in nature. NSUserDefaults is after all just a dictionary. There will be guides on how to model data within core data, there won't be one for migration from NSUserDefaults. If there is I'll eat my pie hat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not surprised that you aren't finding guides, because it's not a very common situation. User defaults and Core Data serve two different purposes so it's unusual to want to migrate from one to the other.

Assuming that your data makes sense for Core Data,

1. Create a new Core Data model and add one or more entities to represent your data.
2. Migrate at app launch, before attempting to use the data.

The migration process would be something like:

1. Check if the data exists in user defaults.
2. If so, read it and create the appropriate managed objects to represent it. Set the attributes of these new objects based on values found in user defaults.
3. Delete the data from user defaults so that next time, step 1 won't trigger a new migration.

The code to do this will be all custom, but it shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: Thanks Tom, for taking the time to break that down for me.